# Lazy loading does not work if the image is inside a block

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I am doing lazy loading in owl. If I place the image in the "owl-item" block, the "owl-loading" class is not replaced with "owl-loaded" in the main container "owl-carousel", as a result of which the slide content is not displayed. If I place the images without the "owl-item", then everything goes fine. Here is my code:

```
<div class = "owl-carousel">
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="image_link"/>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="image_link"/>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="image_link"/>
    </div>
</div>

jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    lazyLoad: true,
    loop: true
});
```

I have to put the image in a block because there will be other markup in addition to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove the class `owl-item` from the markup, then everything starts working correctly.

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="image_link"/>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your JS executed inside a `ready` event ? Also try the class `lazyOwl` instead of `owl-lazy`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items : 4,
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true
  }); 
 
});
```